# An alternative to Mobiwol or any other way to block certain apps from accessing Internet

Tags: android, internet, firewall

I need to control which application on my Android-based phone has or hasn't access to Internet.

Requirements:

- invisible to device user (except for icon in app drawer),
- **password required for disabling** (an absolute must have for me),
- Android 6 supported,
- free or paid,
- **must not require rooted device**.

I've tried [Mobiwol: NoRoot Firewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netspark.firewall&hl=en) and found it great, but with two (very stupid and annoying) exceptions:

- Places icon in notification area with absolutely no way to get rid of it (even ignores system settings -- I have turned off notifications for Mobiwol application and can still see this icon).
- Disabling firewall / unlocking full Internet access requires no password, it is as easy as tapping above mentioned notification and tapping *Disconnect* or opening application and sliding knob from *On* to *Off*; there is absolutely no trace of password in program settings.
- When reboot auto-start is enabled, shows application's main screen with a huge *Firewall Status: On/Off* button.

My 8 years daughter managed to disable this "security protection" in a matter of minutes.

Application itself is very professional, allowing you to define mobile Internet and Wifi access separately, allowing you to control background Internet access etc. But without ability to block removal (or at least making it very hard) from device user it is completely useless.

Do I have any alternative?

Comment: Not any – many, see my listing of [Internet Firewalls](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_firewall#group_377) apps. Thing is, I'm not sure which one fits all your needs, especially the password. Take a look at *NetGuard* first, that's the most flexible no-root solution. I don't know much about the others.

Comment: Yes, I have found your list after posting this question and have scheduled it to review it later (because it is large and impressive). The only bottleneck for me is to filter no-root from root-only solutions, but that's on my side. Thanks for _NetGuard_ suggestion in particular and entire list in general. I assume you could post your comment as a full-featured answer to be accepted by me.

Comment: So does *NetGuard* match your needs? I'm not using it myself, so I cannot tell for sure. Be welcome to post your own answer based on my comments and your experience, as that would be first-hand then :)

Comment: @Izzy Based on your great guide, I installed (but still only briefly tested): NetGuard, NetPatch Firewall and NoRoot Firewall. All three seems to be missing an essential (fundamental?) feature for me of securing disable/enable switch and configuration changes with a password. I simply can't understand this. So far I tested a dozen of a solutions like this and none of them had this. What good do I have of firewall or other means of restricting Internet access on my daugther's phone, if she can disable this "security" in a matter of seconds, because turning it off does not require a password?

Comment: In that case you might also need an [App-Locker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_applocker) :) Though I've heard some ROMs have such integrated (called "protected apps" or the like).

Comment: @Izzy, I'm unable to browse through another 40+ items long list of your wonderful recommendations. Since this is _Soft Rec_ site, can I ask directly, if there is any _particular single one_ app locker application that you recommend? :>

Comment: Of course you can ask directly. It's just that I don't use this kind of software – hence I can only hint, but not give a clear recommendation.